# Convert range of coordinates to A1Notation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to convert range of coordinates to A1Notation. When I put "value" to "A1" of spreadsheet, I get `{"authMode":{},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"columnEnd":1},"source":{},"user":{"nickname":"$$$","email":"$$$@gmail.com"},"value":"value"}` from `e` of `onEdit(e)`. I use below script to get A1Notation of range.

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(typeof e.range) // object
  Logger.log(e.range.getA1Notation()) // A1
}
```

I can get "A1" at `e.range.getA1Notation()`. But when I use below script,

```
function myFunction(){
  var e = {"authMode":{},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"columnEnd":1},"source":{},"user":{"nickname":"$$$","email":"$$$@gmail.com"},"value":"value"};
  Logger.log(typeof e.range) // object
  Logger.log(e.range.getA1Notation()) // Error
}
```

Return error at `Logger.log(e.range.getA1Notation())`. Error message is `TypeError: Cannot find function getA1Notation in object [object Object]`. Both `Logger.log(typeof e.range)` are "object". I have 2 questions here.

1. Why is `e.range.getA1Notation()` of myFunction() the error?
2. Are there any ways to convert from `{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"columnEnd":1}` to A1Notation by `getA1Notation()`?

Thank you so much for your time. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why is `e.range.getA1Notation()` of myFunction() the error?

Because the range property of your object is not of the proper class.

> 2. Are there any ways to convert from `{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"columnEnd":1}` to A1Notation by `getA1Notation()`?

There are many ways. Perhaps the simple way is to get a range using the coordinates set on your object the use getA1Notation on it.

Example:

```
function myFunction(){
  var o = {"columnStart":1,"rowStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"columnEnd":1};
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //
  var row = o.rowStart;
  var column = o.columnStart;
  var numRows = o.rowEnd - o.rowStart + 1;
  var numColumns = o.columnEnd - o.columnStart + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns);
  var A1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(A1Notation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think you say the important answer for me. I am afraid of asking this basic question but, I can't understand the meaning of ``not of the proper class``. What is the meaning of ``not of the proper class``?

Comment: @Elsa : The meaning is that your object is not an object of [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you define a range. Look at the [several methods for getting a range in the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

```
function myFunction(){
  var e = {
    "authMode": {},
    "range": SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1,1,1,1),
    "source":{},
    "user": {
      "nickname":"$$$",
      "email":"$$$@gmail.com"
    },
    "value":"value"
  };
  Logger.log(typeof e.range) // object
  Logger.log(e.range.getA1Notation()) // A1
}

function convert(e) {
  var e = {
    "authMode":{},
    "range":{
      "columnStart":1,
      "rowStart":1,
      "rowEnd":1,
      "columnEnd":1
    },
    "source":{},
    "user":{
      "nickname":"$$$",
      "email":"$$$@gmail.com"
    },
    "value":"value"
  };
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  var column = e.range.columnStart;
  var numRows = e.range.rowEnd - row + 1;
  var numColumns = e.range.columnEnd - column + 1;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns);
  Logger.log(range.getA1Notation()); // A1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can't understand why ``e.range.getA1Notation()`` of myFunction() is the error. How can I see the difference from ``onEdit(e)``?